# Started from 'is part of the declarations of 2 modules', got "Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'"

Tags: angular

I have this shared component used more than once, and was getting the first error. Then I searched online how to import it into a higher level component and got the second error.

---

First error, "is part of the declarations of 2 modules":

`child-1.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        [...]
    ],
    declarations: [
        [...]
        SharedComponent
    ]
})
```

`child-2.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        [...]
    ],
    declarations: [
        [...]
        SharedComponent
    ]
})
```

---

Second error, "Can't bind to 'routerLink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'":

`child-1.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SharedModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        [...]
    ]
})
```

`child-2.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SharedModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        [...]
    ]
})
```

`shared.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { SharedComponent } from './shared.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [],
    exports: [SharedComponent],
    declarations: [SharedComponent],
    providers: []
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have `SharedComponent` in `declarations` of two modules.
Instead add it to `declarations` of **exactly** one module, and also add it to `exports`, and then add the module that contains the component to `imports` where you want to use the shared component as well.

You need to add `RouterModule` to `imports` of every module that contains components that use router directives.

Comment: Got it, I just had to import EVERYTHING being used by that module/component if I want a reusable one.

Comment: There is a youtube video that covers this here if you want more info: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ntJ-P-Cvo7o&t=1s